# Getting values from check boxes to a array by $_POST

Tags: php

My HTML view have a check boxes with in the foreach(looping 3 times).

```
<?php 
$i = 1;
foreach($management_module AS $row){
?>
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="module[]" id="module<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['name']." (".$row['code'].")"; ?>
</label>
</div>
<?php $i++ }?>
```

I get this post value of `module[]` like following in the controller,

```
if(isset($_POST['module'])){
    $data['module']=($_POST['module']);
}
```

`$data['module']` gives the following results.

1. if 1st check box is checked : `Array ( [0] => 1 )`
2. if 2nd check box is checked : `Array ( [0] => 2 )`

But i want the array results like below,

1. -> `Array ( [0] =>1  [1] =>  [2] => )`
2. -> `Array ( [0] =>  [1] => 1 [2] => )`

Please help me to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a hidden field there for each check box which have no value or having value 0.

Do it like below:-

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="module[<?php echo $i;?>]"><!-- you can use value='0' also based on your wish -->
        <input type="checkbox" name="module[<?php echo $i;?>]" id="module<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['name']." (".$row['code'].")"; ?>
    </label>
</div>
```

Output at my local with some hard-code value:-

What i selected:- http://i.share.pho.to/83bb58ca_o.png

What i got after submit:-http://i.share.pho.to/b8474aef_o.png

Comment: What's the extra hidden input for?

Comment: @bassxzero it's for when used not check a check-box then also it's value will go either 0 or empty. which OP want

Comment: This worked Thank you very much. The upvote if from me ;)

Comment: @tenten  glad to help you.:):):)

Answer (score 0):

Add your index to the name of the checkbox.

```
<?php 
$i = 1;
foreach($management_module AS $row){
?>
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="module[<?php echo $i ?>]" id="module<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['name']." (".$row['code'].")"; ?>
</label>
</div>
$i++ }?>
```

Comment: `$i` starts at 1, while OP wants 0-indexed results.

Comment: @roberto06 true, but I don't know if he has js code that is using 1 based indexing. So i'm going to leave it until he says something. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: Plus, the values will be the same as the keys, and not `1`. Still, this is not a bad solution at all, but you should include the PHP treatment, since it will be drastically different from what OP already has.

Answer (score 0):

You could directly set the checkboxes `name` attributes to the row's id (and their values to `1`), as such :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="module[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>]" id="module<?php echo $i ?>" value="1"><?php echo $row['name']." (".$row['code'].")"; ?>
```

Then, in your PHP treatment, loop over all possible checkbox, with a `for` instead of a `foreach` (or a `foreach` on `$management_module`) :

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($management_module); $i++) {
    $data['module'][$i] = (isset($_POST['module'][$i]) ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$module= $_POST['module'];
$size= count($module);

$i = 0;
while ($i < $size) {
    $arraymodule[] = '$module[$i]';
    ++$i;
}
```